# Dial Rotation - Pseudo Code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a dial and when a user touches it, I want it to rotate and follow the users finger round.

I'm just putting this into rough code at the minute and was wondering if this was the correct way to do it before I go ahead and implement it?

```
//on touch
angleOffset = atan2(touchY - centerPointOfDial, touchX - centerPointOfDial);

//on touch move
angle = atan2(touchY - centerPointOfDial, touchX - centerPointOfDial);
dialRotation = (angle - angleOffset)
myDial.rotation = dialRotation;
```

Thanks

Comment: I've just implemented this and it doesn't seem to work correctly. When I start at the top of the dial it says (im debugging the rotation rather than rotating it for now) that the rotation is -180. When I get round to 3'o Clock it then says 0. By the time im at 6'o clock it says 180. Any ideas whats going wrong?

Comment: one, it's not wrong. Rotation is measured relative to the positive X axis, so at 3 o'clock you have 0 degrees of rotation. Also, have you divided by **2 times pi** instead of just **pi?** You need to do so, 1 whole circle = 2 pi radians.

Comment: Which bit needs divinding by 2 x PI?

Comment: @userXXX `float angle = atan2(whatever); float angleInDegrees = angle / (2 * M_PI) * 360;` (or `angle / M_PI * 180`)

Comment: But what about the offset? It jumps back everytime I move it after the first move?

Comment: @userXXX Perhaps because you're not storing the current angle of rotation of the dial wheel.

Comment: Im storing it, just not sure where to put it in the equation.

Comment: @userXXX Also, instead of recalculating the angle every time a touch occurs, why not just `dial.rotation = atan2(touchY - centerPointOfDial, touchX - centerPointOfDial);`?

Comment: This is still not working for me. Jumps whenever I start a rotation. Jumps when I do a full rotation. Any chance you could post your code?

Comment: @userXXX Well, I don't have code handy, but well, just for you, lemme fire up a test project quickly... Wait.

Comment: Damn the simulator, it freezes, I gotta test it on the device, but that takes longer... Well, the formula I wrote should work, keep trying...

Comment: Your formula doesnt work, as soon as the rotation gets to 90 it jumps to a minus figure.